# Sudden Activation of network connection failed? 18.10

Tags: networking, asus, 18.10, connection

So I have an Asus laptop with no problems, dual boot Windows 10. I came home from work today to find the internet not working for Ubuntu 18.10. It worked fine last night, with no interruptions. All other laptops/ cell phones are connected just fine, and the internet is working. Only my laptop is  showing, "Connection failed activation of network connection failed." I've restarted the laptop twice and did a complete shut off/rest for ten minutes and it did not help. I can connect if I am hardwired, it's the wifi that is randomly giving me trouble. I am new to Ubuntu and need help trying to figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is my only computer. Thanks!

Edit: I'm using wi-fi and a Bluetooth dongle. Again, no problems before...just randomly became an issue.